# Sort list by date flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to sort the list by date, but sorting only by first number.

I get this format from JSON `20-JAN-23`

and I'm trying to order with `model.data.sort((a, b) => b.time!.compareTo(a.time!));`

I need to sort the list by date.

I get this format from JSON `20-JAN-23`

and I'm trying to order with `model.data.sort((a, b) => b.time!.compareTo(a.time!));`

but if the year is different, sort only by day. I need to sort by full date.

e.x:

```
20-SEP-20
```

```
02-DEC-21
```

```
29-JAN-23
```

```
12-JUN-20
```

My sorting is :

```
02-DEC-21
12-JUN-20
20-SEP-20
29-JAN-23
```

but I want to be:

```
12-JUN-20
20-SEP-20
02-DEC-21
29-JAN-23
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

int sortDates(String a, String b) {
  String formatDate(String s) => s.replaceRange(4, 6, s.substring(4, 6).toLowerCase());
  DateTime parse(String s) => DateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").parse(formatDate(s));
  return parse(a).compareTo(parse(b));
}

...
model.data.sort(sortDates);
...
```